# How to show only 1 image from an image list/set on the homepage in django html homepage template?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am trying to show only 1 image from a list of images on the homepage. I am using django and its template engine. I use a formset to upload images onto the database, now the problem is when I loop through the list in the homepage, it shows all the images, I want to show only the first image from the set in the homepage. How to implement that? This is the code I have.

```
{% for image in post.postimage_set.all %}
    <img class="" style="content: center" height="300" 
        width="300" src="{{ image.images.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use a loop to get only one element? Isn't there a `.get` or some method like that to get an element from your list?

Comment: Hey, I tried to display one element from the array, but I am not sure how to correctly do it, so I thought I would loop through it and show only one image, but its showing me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by checking the current index value of the forloop and render the img tag only if the index value is 1.

You can access index value by `{{ forloop.counter }}`

or you can use `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` which starts index from 0 so you can render image tag if it is equal to 0

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Can you give an example?  So you mean should I change the forloop?

Comment: I mean you can use `{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}` to render that img tag inside that for loop

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` is traversing through all the images and displaying them all.

If i understood what you are asking, you only want 1 image per visit to the page and not a carousel, right? So why don't you just random a number between the options you have in your **view** and then pass the random image to the **template** instead of getting a random image from all the available ones on the template?

This way you are only passing one image which is decided by the view and not passing all the images to the template and then let the template select a random one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response... did you mean like this? `<img src="{{ images[0].url }}" />` or something? this is giving me an error. can you give an example?